# Why setting shapeAppearanceModel in MaterialCardView stops childclipping?

Tags: android, android-cardview, materialcardview

My usecase is to edit shapeAppearanceModel for `com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView`

```
card.shapeAppearanceModel = card.shapeAppearanceModel
            .toBuilder()
            .setTopEdge(TriangleEdgeTreatment(triangleSize))
            .build()
```

Above code is working as expected But due to above programatically setup of shapeAppearanceModel

### xml

```
 <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="?myCustomColor"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation=4dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="false">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/myImageDrawable"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

In Android studio as the TopEdge is define programatically Editor is not replicating the bug but in Emulator/Real device the child is not getting clipped and The Rounded Corners are getting overlapped by ImageView.

> And when i remove the shapeAppearanceModel setup the clipping work's
> as expected.

### ScreenShot

[image: Bug]

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is Because `MaterialCardView` locked `clipToOutline` behaviour only whe the Shape is Marked as Rounded and unfortunately, that implementation also locked by the component it self by default :

here if you open MaterialCardView.java, you can find this code:

```java
@Override
  public void setShapeAppearanceModel(@NonNull ShapeAppearanceModel shapeAppearanceModel) {
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
      setClipToOutline(shapeAppearanceModel.isRoundRect(getBoundsAsRectF()));
    }
    cardViewHelper.setShapeAppearanceModel(shapeAppearanceModel);
  }
```

and if you go deeper, the implementation of `isRoundRect`, would be like this :

```java
@RestrictTo(LIBRARY_GROUP)
  public boolean isRoundRect(@NonNull RectF bounds) {
    boolean hasDefaultEdges =
        leftEdge.getClass().equals(EdgeTreatment.class)
            && rightEdge.getClass().equals(EdgeTreatment.class)
            && topEdge.getClass().equals(EdgeTreatment.class)
            && bottomEdge.getClass().equals(EdgeTreatment.class);

    float cornerSize = topLeftCornerSize.getCornerSize(bounds);

    boolean cornersHaveSameSize =
        topRightCornerSize.getCornerSize(bounds) == cornerSize
            && bottomLeftCornerSize.getCornerSize(bounds) == cornerSize
            && bottomRightCornerSize.getCornerSize(bounds) == cornerSize;

    boolean hasRoundedCorners =
        topRightCorner instanceof RoundedCornerTreatment
            && topLeftCorner instanceof RoundedCornerTreatment
            && bottomRightCorner instanceof RoundedCornerTreatment
            && bottomLeftCorner instanceof RoundedCornerTreatment;

    return hasDefaultEdges && cornersHaveSameSize && hasRoundedCorners;
  }
```

there's a condition to make it return true will be if the shape has the same or all corner rounded.

You can't trick that by programmatically set `card.setClipToOutline(true)` because it happended after the render proses.

The reason they make it that way because of some limitation by design :

(further reading : https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1950)

The Good News you can solve that by creating your own `MaterialCardView` and override some implementation like this :

```java
package com.example.myapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView;
import com.google.android.material.shape.ShapeAppearancePathProvider;

public class MaskedCardView extends MaterialCardView {
    private ShapeAppearancePathProvider pathProvider = new ShapeAppearancePathProvider();
    private Path path = new Path();
    private RectF rectF = new RectF(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);

    public MaskedCardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MaskedCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MaskedCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.clipPath(path);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        rectF.right = (float) w;
        rectF.bottom = (float) h;
        pathProvider.calculatePath(getShapeAppearanceModel(), 1f, rectF, path);
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }
}
```

I hope it can answer your question.